# Android - Preserving the ids of photos after a query and saving data into a database

Tags: android, sqlite, android-contentresolver, photo-gallery

I'm working on an application where I need query photos, apply some edits and save the those edits for later use.

I'm thinking of using a sqlite database to save the edits (applied values when editing) and use the photo ids returned from photo query as the keys. So, I can retrieve the correct set of edits for a given photo.

My first question is, would it be safe to assume that the ids retrieved from the query (Using getContext().getContentResolver().query()) would not change over time when the new photos are added or deleted from the phone?

My second question is, do you see any pit falls of using a sqlite database for storing the edits for each photo? Any recommendations/thoughts about the architecture would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your second question, I think it's a good approach to use a local DB. I'd do the same.

I don't think it's the best approach to rely on the IDs. This is how I would solve it: I'd have a "original_id" column in the photos table, that can be nullable. So, original photos will have this field set as null, and edited photos will have the original image's ID in this field. So, when I need to retrieve a set of edits for a given photo, I'd query by original_id and retrieve the full set of editions.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks Nadia. I'm little confused with your answer for the first question.  You mentioned that replying on IDs might not be a good idea. Then again, you recommended to store original image ids in the photo table. Isn't that the original image ids and queried ids are the same? And when you mentioned adding a column to photo table, you mean the local db table. right? Please clarify if you can. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I meant, that the IDs won't change if they're set as autoincremental, but you should keep a reference to the original photo for each photo edit (otherwise, how would you know a determined edit belongs to a certain photo). It's better doing it like this than relying on the fact that photo IDs 3, 4 and 8, for example, are edits of photo 1, understand? This way, you don't care about the IDs.

And yes, when I mentioned adding a column, I meant the local SQLite DB.

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks Nadia.

Comment: You're welcome! Please accept my answer if it's ok for you :).